# Using topic function in republish topic aws iot core from terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-iot-core

I try to create iot rule like this using terraform module https://github.com/QuiNovas/terraform-aws-iot-topic-rule

```
module "iot_rule_2" {
  name = "xxx"
  sql_query = "xxx"
  source = "QuiNovas/iot-topic-rule/aws"
  version = "1.0.4"
  republish = [{topic = "$$aws/things/${topic(3)}/shadow/name/datamodel/update"}]
}
```

and I get the error

```
Error: Call to unknown function
│
│   on main.tf line 52, in module "iot_rule_2":
│   52:   republish = [{topic = "$$aws/things/${topic(3)}/shadow/name/datamodel/update"}]
│
│ There is no function named "topic".
```

The topic function exists in AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html

Comment: What do you think ${topic(3)}/shadow/name/datamodel/update"}]
} does?

Comment: It should republish the message from the topic defined in SQL query (xxx) to topic "$$aws/things/${topic(3)}/shadow/name/datamodel/update" - topic(3) should be a thing id as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/republish-rule-action.html 

It works fine when created from AWS Console (GUI) I just try to automate the deployment a bit.

Comment: Or check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-substitution-templates.html and tell me if I can do this using terraform plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution - we should prefix with additional $.

```
module "iot_rule_2" {
  name = "xxx"
  sql_query = "xxx"
  source = "QuiNovas/iot-topic-rule/aws"
  version = "1.0.4"
  republish = [{topic = "$$aws/things/$${topic(3)}/shadow/name/datamodel/update"}]
}
```

Comment: This happens because the first $ runs a terraform function, so if you use ${timestamp} it will run the timestamp function timestamp during the terraform apply operation and will be the same timestamp every time the iot rule is triggered, while $${timestamp()} escapes the $ operator and writes in the rule the ${timestamp()} function, so it will be the iot rule that will run this function and not Terraform.